# TRAMP mode hangs while copy large file from remote to local via Ssh

Tags: tramp, ssh

Trying here to download (`scp` file from remote to local) that was considered large file, then Emacs tried to compact it, then got stuck.

Even used `scp` command to do it because copying via `ssh` got stuck too.

Now there are two goals here: one is repair file copy from remote to local via `ssh` or set it to do not compact large files for copy via `scp` on TRAMP mode, but copy it at normal size.

Any ideas?

Comment: If `scp` without Emacs is failing, it doesn't seem likely that Emacs will fare any better.  I would try to debug the first issue.

Comment: Tramp's internal `scp` command does not compress. I recommend to set `tramp-verbose` to 6, and check the resulting debug buffer for the commands Tramp has used. Search for lines containing `(6)`.

Comment: Already set `tramp-verbose` 6, but application stucks when starting compression, then can't reach the log buffer. How the logs could be accessed? `scp` e `ssh` works just fine out of Emacs, only stucks while compressing.

Comment: Just a blind shot: set `tramp-inline-compress-start-size` to `nil`.

Comment: And how would that be done?

Comment: `(setq tramp-inline-compress-start-size nil)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRAMP uses itself Base64 encoding, it doesn't hangs, just takes a really long time for larger files.

Maybe `rsync` or `rcp` methods speeds up the process, but this is its basis.

What may be done is run a shell command in minibuffer, via `M-!`, then enter `scp` as outside of Emacs, and without using TRAMP mode, it would accelerate it significantly, with regular `scp` speed.

Answer (score 3):

Try stablishing connection using `scp` itself instead of `ssh`, as of `/scp:user@host#port:/directory`, and then using `scp` again, as managed here to don't use `base64` conversion, which seems to be slowing the transfer.